Union type refuses to accept falsey value
I get an error trying to work with what I think is a custom union type.
export type ServerResponse = { token: string; result: any } | { token: string; error: any };

export function handleNotificationsResponse(
    supabase: SupabaseClient,
    results: ServerResponse[]
): Promise<null> {
    let deletes = results.map((res) => {
        return res.error ? deleteSubByToken(supabase, res.token) : Promise.resolve(null);
             //^^^^^^^^^
    });
    return Promise.all(deletes).then(() => null);
}

The error is:
Property 'error' does not exist on type 'ServerResponse'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type '{ token: string; result: any; }'.

which is true but res.error should be falsey when the version with result is returned. I don't love falsey but I don't see anything wrong as such.

error doesn't exist on both members of the union. So you need to narrow res to access that property (e.g. you could .filter with a type predicate, so you get an array only containing the error cases - https://tsplay.dev/NBd0kW).

Honestly, I thought what I had was 'narrowing' but it seems not

You have to narrow before it will be safe to access res.error. Yes in JS res.error will just be undefined so the ternary is fine, but TS is there to disallow some things that work in JS.

Seems to type check with
return 'error' in res ? deleteSubByToken(supabase, res.token) : Promise.resolve(null);

thanks @jonrsharpe
